# nuxt.render not working in production mode for Nuxt SPA

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

The following code runs in the standard Nuxt `server/index.js` just fine in development mode when starting up my SPA app.

```
// Init Nuxt.js
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

// Build only in dev mode
if (config.dev) {
  const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
  await builder.build()
}

// Give nuxt middleware to express
app.use(nuxt.render)
```

When deployed and in production mode, the build process is skipped (which is what I want) but nuxt.render() fails because it has not been initialized by `builder.build()`.

I've tried everything I can think of and can't find a solution where it simply renders a pre-built app as it LOOKS like it is supposed to do.

Comment: That shouldnt happen. And it is working like u described. But u need to make sure that u build your app before start in production. E.g. deployed .nuxt folder

Comment: I'd assumed that if you build it in dev mode, the build folder is already built and usable. In the meantime I solved it by using the nuxt-start package. It is most likely  because I am a newb but it is not easy to get your head around. I built in dev mode then comment out the build process in the above script. That doesn't work for me.

Comment: build for dev is different than building for production. You need nuxt build and then nuxt start :)